# Inline HTML ng-templates not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, cloud9-ide

I'm following a tutorial on [Thinkster](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#beginning-node) to learn Angular and MEAN Stack, however I for some reason can't get my template to load inline with my loaded HTML. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here? The code isn't coloring correctly, and the page doesn't render anything when loaded in a browser.

What am I not understanding about this? The template tags seem to not be matching?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Flapper News</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <style>.glyphicon-thumbs-up {cursor:pointer}</style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="flapperNews"><!--ng-controller="MainCtrl" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;"-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Start template -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Flapper News</h1>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
                {{post.upvotes}}
                <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.title}}">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </a>
                    <span ng-hide="post.link">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <h3>Add a new post</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        ng-model="title"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Link"
                        ng-model="link"></input>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>    
            </form>
        </script> 
        <!-- end template -->
        <!-- start template -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
          <div class="page-header">
            <h3>
                <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                    {{post.title}}
                </a>
                <span ng-hide="post.link">
                    {{post.title}}
                </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
            {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                {{comment.body}}
            </span>
          </div>
        </script>
        <!-- end template -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
```

Here's my app.js

```
    /*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);
app.factory('posts',[function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','posts', function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 12},
        {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 14},
        {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 16},
        {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 11},
        {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 1}
        ];
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {return;}
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title, 
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    }
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
        post.upvotes += 1;
    }
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [ '$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    }]);
```

Comment: Change the ui-router address the one that you are using isnt valid. Here is the new one http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js

Comment: @Konkko this still doesn't solve the problem. The HTML tags aren't working

Comment: Can you post the code where you define your module?

Comment: @bumpy just added it now

Comment: Why are you defining your module twice? (first two lines in app.js) It should be `var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);`
;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your angular-ui-router.js library address it's cloudfare not cloudflare.

## EDIT

Remove the unnecessary `;` from the home state

`.state('home', {
   url: '/home',
   templateUrl: '/home.html',
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
});`

and remove the line `angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);`
add the `ui.router` to the first line `var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);`

To working JS:

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ["ui.router"]);
app.factory('posts',[function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','posts', function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 12},
        {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 14},
        {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 16},
        {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 11},
        {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 1}
        ];
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {return;}
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title, 
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    }
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
        post.upvotes += 1;
    }
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [ '$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    }]);
```

HTML:

Comment: @bdeo see the edited answer. This should work here is a working Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/u42STTpQVYATSydzMYeA

Comment: So this seems to work and I can see it in plunker but i suppose it's now a c9 issue because c9 isn't displaying correctly. @Konkko

Comment: @bdeo please post the issue, with what you think is the problem with Cloud9 (screenshots and code snippets welcome), on community.c9.io and we'll be happy to help.